# Finding the geometry of induced electric fields using Faraday's law

Tags: maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction

Thinking of a long straight wire carrying increasing or decreasing current, we know by using Faraday's law of induction that the magnetic field produced by this wire will induce an electric field. Now, to apply Faraday's law a circular or rectangular conducting loop can be placed beside this wire such that the magnetic field is directed parallel to the normal of the loop surface. If these conducting loops are removed, however, then there should still be a circular or rectangular electric field next to the wire. But which one is it?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. A changing magnetic field is always accompanied by an electric field.  What do imaginary conducting loops have to do with anything?

Comment: @J.Murray . The question is more specifically about the geometry of the electric field lines formed by induction. Using an imaginary conducting loop, you can find the direction of the current and thus the direction of the electric field around the loop. If you remove this imaginary conducting loop, I am wondering if the electric fields will still have the geometry of the loop, which may be different shapes depending on which shape you choose